# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: branches, but argument is supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a subclass of another class. Both have the same signature for the `__init__` method. My caller supplies all required arguments. Yet I still get the missing argument error.

I have tried different ways of calling the super class's `__init__` method.

**Base Class init function (imported from another file):**

```py
class Gerrit:
    connections = {
        'consumer': MyGerritClient(host='gerrit.consumer.com', username=getpass.getuser()),
        'b2b': MyGerritClient(host='gerrit.b2b.com', username=getpass.getuser())
    }

    def __init__(self, segment, rev_id, branches):
        print("TRACE: Gerrit::__init__()")
        self.branches = branches
        self.review = None  # Type: GerritChange
        self.gerrit_client = self.connections[segment]
        for review_candidate in self.gerrit_client.query(rev_id):
            if self.branch_is_valid(review_candidate.branch) and review_candidate.status != 'ABANDONED':
                self.review = review_candidate
        self.approved = False
        self.rev_id = rev_id
        self.merged = False
```

**Child Class `__init__` method:**

```py
class CvGerrit(Gerrit):
    def __init__(self, segment, rev_id, branches):
        Gerrit.__init__(segment, rev_id, branches)
```

**Caller:**

```py
review = CvGerrit(segment='consumer', rev_id=gerrit_id, branches=my_branches)
```

I expect that I can construct the child class, `CvGerrit`. Instead I get the missing positional argument error. Does it matter that the other uses of the base class take a `list` for the branches argument, while the caller is passing a `dict`? This is intentional, and the whole reason for the subclassing, that I may process this collection differently using an overridden function in the child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to call either

```
Gerrit.__init__(self, segment, rev_id, branches)
```

or

```
super().__init__(segment, rev_id, branches)
```

By itself, `__init__` is just another function object, so when you access it through the class, you must pass *all* parameters, including `self`. When you access it through an instance or `super`, you get a bound method with `self` already pre-inserted into the argument list.

Comment: Thank you! I just couldn't see that for some reason.